# how to copy weights of a trained network to another one in pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I have trained a neural network with layers 4,5,6 not commented in **init** (#1 lines) and as you see they were not used in forwarding process so they are not used at all, but increased the size of network.so now I want to continue training with network below (with commented #1 lines which means the network is technically the same) but I don't want to start from beginning and I don't know how to transfer trained weights and biases to new neural network.

```
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.lin = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.Tanh = torch.nn.Tanh()
        self.leakyrelu =nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01, inplace=False)
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.l3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1100)
#         self.l4 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size) #1
#         self.l5 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size) #1
#         self.l6 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size) #1
        self.lout = nn.Linear(1100, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        # out = self.relu(out)
        # out = torch.sigmoid(out)
        # out = self.Tanh(out)
        # out = self.leakyrelu(out)
        out = self.lin(x)
        out = self.leakyrelu(out)
        out = self.l2(out)
        out = self.Tanh(out)
        out = self.l3(out)
        out = self.Tanh(out)
        # out = self.l4(out)
        # out = self.leakyrelu(out)
        # out = self.l5(out)
        # out = self.leakyrelu(out)
        # out = self.l6(out)
        # out = self.leakyrelu(out)
        out = self.lout(out)
        
        # no activation and no softmax at the end
        return out
```

Comment: manipulate the `state_dict` directly.

Comment: @Shai kinda don't know how to do that, tried with [wlin, blin] = model.lin.parameters()
[wl2, bl2] = model.l2.parameters()
[wl3, bl3] = model.l3.parameters()
[wlout, blout] = model.lout.parameters() but for changing the `w[0][0]` to another number got error RuntimeError: a view of a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.

Comment: you should change the `state_dict`, which is an `OrderedDict` object. Once it is changed, use `load_state_dict` to load the modified weights to the model.

Comment: no, the `load_state_dict` gives error, I had tried that.

Comment: you need to **modify** the `state_dict` before loading it